# Effect of cftransaction rollback along with multiple cftransaction commits

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle11g, coldfusion-7

Within a `cftransaction` block, what does rollback do when I have multiple commit actions?

```
<cftransaction>
  <cftry>
    <cfquery ...>
    <cfquery ...>
    <cftransaction action="commit" />
    <cfquery ...>
    <cfquery ...>
    <!--- Everything went fine --->
    <cftransaction action="commit">
  <cfcatch>
    <cftransaction action="rollback">
  </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
</cftransaction>
```

If there is an error caught, will the rollback cancel *everything* all the time, or only back to the last commit action?

Note that this is existing code written by others. I'm just trying to make sure it works as is and how.

The database runs under Oracle 11g if this should change the behavior.

Comment: I would expect it to only rollback to the last commit (or the start of the transaction) but I've not verified that. With CF8 and newer you can use `action="setsavepoint"` to do partial rollbacks, but dunno if there's a way to achieve that with CF7.